# Scala Camel - Common code after choice and otherwise

Tags: scala, apache-camel

I have a scenario, where some code needs to go into choice, some in otherwise, and some common clean-up code needs to be executed after that in both scenarios. I tried the following piece of code, but could not achieve what I wanted. Basically it would consider all the code after otherwise as a part of otherwise. In the following scenario, 'Should Reach Here in all scenarios' is being printed only in case of otherwise. Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong ?

```
  .choice(){ 
    when(exchange => exchange.getIn.getBody(classOf[String]) != null){ 
      process(new ResponseProcessor) 
      .log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"File with content: ${body}") 
      .log("Completed Job") 
    } otherwise{ 
      log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"Empty Body") 
    } 
  } 
  .log("Should Reach Here in all scenarios")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Scala DSL, you can use the simple flavor (fluent API) for smaller, simple routes.  Because it is built directly on top of the normal Java fluent API, it does suffer from some of the same problems (like e.g. the need for explicit end() API calls to delimit some blocks).

For more advanced routes, you can use another style of the Scala DSL, which does use proper Scala code blocks instead.  The main difference is to avoid the use of the . before the different method calls in your example:

```
  "direct:start" ==> {
    choice(){
      when(exchange => exchange.getIn.getBody(classOf[String]) != null) {
        process(new ResponseProcessor)
        log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"File with content: ${body}")
        log("Completed Job")
      } otherwise {
        log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"Empty Body")
      }
    }
    log("Should Reach Here in all scenarios")
  }
```

Using Camel 2.12.1 and Scala 2.10.3, this does give me the expected output in the logs:

```
780 [main] INFO route1 - Empty Body
783 [main] INFO route1 - Should Reach Here in all scenarios
784 [main] INFO route1 - File with content: What a beautiful day!!
784 [main] INFO route1 - Completed Job
784 [main] INFO route1 - Should Reach Here in all scenarios
```